# REVOKE privileges ON table doesn't work on AMAZON AURORA (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I executed this query

```
REVOKE ALL ON dbname.tablename FROM 'user'@'%';
```

Next I executed

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But I still can select data from `tablename`
What's wrong?

Comment: Aurora and RDS don't give you SUPER privilege, so you probably cannot change another user's SUPER privilege. ALL includes SUPER.

Comment: `REVOKE` only revokes what has been *explicitly* granted.  *Implicit* table grants from a higher level (such as `ON dbname.*`) would not be impacted.  Show us the results of `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'%';` and the problem should become apparent.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, you re right! Just forget about this!

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk you can delete a question that has no answers.  Otherwise, I've cast the first vote to close it as a "problem that can no longer be reproduced."